# How can I get OpenGL to draw the character at the location I want?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm currently working on getting text drawn to the screen in openGL. I have a function which works as long as I don't want the text to go across multiple lines and I really want the text to be green. Obviously, this isn't ideal. The function that I'm currently using is:

```
void Scene::DrawString(std::string text, position pos)
{
    void* font = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_12;
    float rightOfScreen = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);

    std::vector<std::string> sentence = split(text, ' ');

    glRasterPos2f(pos.x, pos.z);
    glColor3i(0, 0, 0); //Black text
    double rasterPosition[4]; //GL raster position returns 4 doubles. It just does, and it needs to go into an array

    for (auto word : sentence)
    {
        int wordWidth = 0;
        for (char c : word)
        {
            wordWidth += glutBitmapWidth(font, c);
        }

        glGetDoublev(GL_CURRENT_RASTER_POSITION, rasterPosition);
        if (rasterPosition[0] + wordWidth > rightOfScreen)
        {
            pos.z += 1;
            glRasterPos2d(pos.x, pos.z);
        }

        for (char c : word)
        {
            glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
        }

        glutBitmapCharacter(font, ' ');
    }
}
```

(Position is a struct with two floats - x and z)

When I pass in a string that should be wrapped onto the next line, it is correctly detecting when the word should be pushed, but glRasterPos2d is just overlaying the second part over the top of the first (as well as fixing the colour issue where it's getting rendered green instead of black).

My question is; how do I do the equivalent of putting in a newline character?

Comment: What are your modelview and projection transformations? The position passed to `glRasterPos()` is transformed with the current transformations. Depending on how you set up the transformations, you might be moving each line by only 1 pixel, since you add 1 to the position.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Render the second line the same way you rendered the first, but a little lower. How much lower depends on your font height and how much line padding you desire.

At this level, *you* are responsible for writing the "newline" semantics!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. I thought performing the glRasterPos2f call with an increased "y" value and then continuing to call glutBitmapCharacter should do the newline thing

Comment: @Yann: I'm confused. Didn't you just say in the question that that _doesn't_ happen? So why would you now expect it to happen? Have you read the documentation?!

Comment: I'm not going to say that it was a comprehensive read, but I thought I understood. The first call to it set the start position of the string correctly, and since it is being drawn character by character I'd assumed that any subsequent calls to glPosition should reset the "carriage" as it were.

Comment: @Yann: Well now you know what assuming does :) OpenGL is not a word processor; it doesn't render "paragraphs". On the contrary — _applications_ (like yours) render "paragraphs", and they use the raw features of OpenGL to do it. The utility of auto-advancing the _x_ position is all you get, AFAIK.